# ... to feel sick Tuesday afternoon / on Tuesday afternoon / from Tuesday afternoon. Which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, differences, prepositions, word-usage

Are these all correct?

1. He was feeling good on Monday, but he started to feel sick Tuesday
   afternoon.
2. He was feeling good on Monday, but he started to feel sick on Tuesday
   afternoon.
3. He was feeling good on Monday, but he started to feel sick from
   Tuesday afternoon.

Comment: In the US the 3rd form would probably not be used (though easily understood).  You can have your pick of the other two.  Lacking further context it would be difficult to distinguish a difference in meaning between them.

Comment: Validity of the first one depends what regional variety of English you're using. What country are you in?

Answer (score 1):

first example is the best;

second is OK with identical meaning;

third is either ungrammatical or does not mean what was intended.

See my comment.

Comment: Comments  can be deleted at any time, why can't you copy and paste them in your "answer"?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: my comments are mainly in refutation of Chatterjee's answer. I would rather have people read them in context of that thread. Otherwise I would have to rephrase them.

Answer (score -1):

Meanings vary here.

*feel sick Tuesday afternoon*  can mean - ...felt that Tuesday afternoon was sick.
(Such usage is discouraged as meaning becomes ambiguous).

*to feel sick on Tuesday afternoon* = He felt that he was falling sick sometime during Tuesday afternoon.

*to feel sick from Tuesday afternoon* = ...(reported at a later time, say on a Friday) that he fell sick on Tuesday afternoon and the sickness continues.

Comment: In AmE the phrasing "started to feel sick FROM Tuesday afternoon" would either be taken to mean he (later) felt sick from (whatever happened on) Tuesday afternoon, or it would seem redundant (if he STARTED, it was ON tuesday, not FROM Tuesday). More likely, you might hear "He felt sick FROM from Tuesday afternoon ONWARD" or "He has felt sick SINCE Tuesday afternoon". As for the interpretation "felt that Tuesday afternoon was sick"—this would never be misconstrued that way in AmE.

Comment: +1 I agree with the use of 'since' in place of 'from' in the third statement. I don't think either of them are wrong, though. As for the 'sick Tuesday afternoon', consider - "As the doctors stepped out in the leper's colony, they were greeted by the sick Tuesday afternoon."  In fact, Tuesday afternoons have often been hot, sunny and many other things.

Comment: @Mayanprateek: But the construction "started to feel sick" lets us know that the sentence was about his health, and alerts us that what follows will tell us WHEN that feeling started. There is no ambiguity.

Comment: @Mayanprateek: As for your leper's colony example, I parse it as the doctors were greeted by "the sick" (that is, the lepers) and it happened to be Tuesday (that is, my mind rearranges "Tuesday afternoon" to what seems its proper place, after "colony", so as to modify "stepped".) No, I cannot imagine a "sick Tuesday", other than in a rap lyric (in AAVE, this would mean a really great Tuesday afternoon—but that interpretation would not occur to me viewing your example.) Perhaps this is just a difference between American English and Indian English (dare I presume that you are from India?)

Comment: +1 Sharp, aren't you :)  I happen to come from a more conservative line of usage. I still shudder at the thought of Utpal da (God bless him) shouting in my ear - Why did you skip that preposition! Anyway, I'm swayed to this opinion because I read too much of London from  Arthur Conan Doyle. To cite - _the Adventure of the Missing Three-Quarter_  "...but I have a particular recollection of one which reached us on **a gloomy February morning** some seven or eight years ago." Views?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: done

Comment: It has to be approved first; I don't have instant edit privilege.

Comment: Your " 'feel sick Tuesday afternoon' can mean - ...'felt that Tuesday afternoon was sick' uses a V - PreDA - O construction almost as outlandish as 'I consider stupid John'. It's non-idiomatic if not ungrammatical.

Comment: @Chatterjee: the thing about OP's first example is that to be understood as being about the type of afternoon it was, it would have to be worded "...he started to feel [a / the] sick Tuesday afternoon..."  (or ... to feel Sick Tuesday —you know, like Fat Tuesday?)